# pyspark transform to find offset start and end

Tags: pyspark

In Pyspark, trying to find offsets based on length array column "Col1". Don't want to use UDF, so trying to get solution using transform. But facing errors. Please suggest any workaround

```
Col1            Offset
[3,4,6,2,1]     [[0,3],[4,8],[9,15],[16,18],[19,20]]
[10,5,4,3,2]    [[0,10],[11,16],[17,21],[22,25],[26,28]]

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, expr


 spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("Calculate Offset Column") \
.getOrCreate()


 data = [([3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 2.0, 1.0],),
    ([10.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0],)]


 df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Col1"])
 df = df.withColumn("Offsets", 
               f.expr("""transform(Col1, (x, i) -> struct(coalesce(sum(Col1) over (order by i rows between unbounded preceding and current row) - x, 0) as start, 
                                                         sum(Col1) over (order by i rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as end))"""))
```

> Error: Resolved attribute(s) i#462 missing from Col1#454 in operator !Window [Col1#454, transform(Col1#454, lambdafunction(struct(start, coalesce((sum(cast(Col1 as double)) windowspecdefinition(lambda i#462 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) - lambda x#461), cast(0 as double)), end, sum(cast(Col1 as double)) windowspecdefinition(lambda i#462 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$()))), lambda x#461, lambda i#462, false)) AS Offsets#458], [lambda i#462 ASC NULLS FIRST].;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("Calculate Offset Column") \
.getOrCreate()


data = [([3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 2.0, 1.0],),
    ([10.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0],)]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Col1"])

df = (df
       .withColumn("Offsets_tmp", 
           F.expr("""transform(Col1, (x, i) -> (i,x))"""))
       .select("Col1",F.explode("Offsets_tmp").alias("expl"))
       .selectExpr(
           "Col1"
           ,"SUM(expl.x) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY expl)+expl.i right_side"
           ,"CASE WHEN expl.i = 0 THEN 0 ELSE right_side-expl.x END left_side"
           ,"ARRAY(left_side, right_side) arr1"
       )
       .groupBy("Col1")
       .agg(F.collect_list("arr1").alias("Offset"))
       .select("Col1",F.array_sort("Offset").alias("Offset"))
      )

df.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Col1                      |Offset                                                               |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 2.0, 1.0] |[[0.0, 3.0], [4.0, 8.0], [9.0, 15.0], [16.0, 18.0], [19.0, 20.0]]    |
|[10.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0]|[[0.0, 10.0], [11.0, 16.0], [17.0, 21.0], [22.0, 25.0], [26.0, 28.0]]|
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Tested and works on Spark 3.5.0.

Note: it might not be the prettiest option, you could replace most of the `selectExpr` with some nice PySpark code (e.g., `pyspark.sql.Window`).
My personal preference is for SQL in terms of Window functions, though, as they are a bit less verbose in my opinion.

EDIT: added `array_sort`. Not sure if it matters to you or not, but `collect_list` might return the elements in a different order after a shuffle. Since the `Offset` column is expected to be monotonically ascending, then `array_sort` can be used to have a deterministic output.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting below error ,  looks like right_side is not detected as column
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`right_side`' given input columns: [Col1, expl]; line 1 pos 33;

Comment: Hmm, which version of Spark are you using? I am on 3.5.0 and I don't get this error.
I did have a mistake in the code here: I had accidentally placed `.alias("Offset")` on the wrong side of a bracket for the code on SO. I updated the code, and executing this on Spark 3.5 works.
Alternatively, if you still get the error and you're on an older version of Spark, what should work is separating the `selectExpr` to multiple lines, e.g. `.selectExpr("...", "... right_side").selectExpr("*","... left_side")[...etc...]`

Comment: It works now after adding separate selectExpr lines due to old spark